# PHP allow img tags only

Tags: php, weblogic, strip-tags

I need your assistence related php. In php, i want to allow html `<img>` tags only, i tried php's built-in function `strip_tags()` but it's not giving me the output i need. For instance, in the following code `strip_tags()` allows img tags but along with text.

```
$img = "<img src='/img/fawaz.jpg' alt= ''> <br /> <p> This is a detailed paragraph about Fawaz and his mates.</p>";
echo strip_tags($img , "<img>");
```

What would be the proper way to just allow `<img>` or any tag only from the function or variable. 
Any help 'd be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, can you rephrase that? Better yet, show us what output you expect.

Comment: are you trying to extract the `<img/>` tags or the `innerHTML`?

Comment: @stillstanding: Yes, I want to extract <code> <img /> </code> tags only, don't want any <p>, text,or any other tag.

Comment: @deceze: From the <code>$img</code> variable, i want the image as an output only.

Comment: Use backticks to highlight code here, otherwise your question gets confusing! http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @deceze: From the `$img` variable, i want the image as an output only.

Comment: @deceze: Sorry, i'm New to StackOverFlow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be due to non closing img tag in your code. Try this

```
$img = "<img src='/img/fawaz.jpg' alt= '' /> <br /> <p> This is a detailed paragraph about Fawaz and his mates.</p>";
echo strip_tags($img , "<img>");
```

Comment: The format is HTML-valid, but `strip_tags` doesn't really care about that. It also works without the closing `/`.

Comment: It's not working, dude. By the way, strip_tags() has the ability to close HTML tags by itself. You don't need to pass parameters like strip_tags($img , "<p></p>");, BUT just ( , "<p>").

Comment: @Fawaz, didn't know that strip_tags closes the tags! Very happy to know this! Thanks! +1

Answer (score 2):

`strip_tags()` doesn't work that way you want it to behave. If supplied with a second argument, the tags listed are allowed to be part of the resulting string - except those which are not listed. And it will not filter out inner text.

If you want to extract `<img/>` elements only, don't even think about using a regex. Use a DOM parser for that:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc=new DOMDocument;
$html=$doc->loadHTML('<img src="/img/fawaz.jpg" alt= ""> <br /> <p> This is a
detailed paragraph about Fawaz and his mates.</p>');
$path=new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach ($path->query('//img') as $found)
    var_dump($doc->saveXML($found));
```

Comment: @stillstanding: I saw this snippet somewhere visiting in StackOverFlow. Is this the only solution ??

Comment: As stated, using a regex is an alternative - but don't bother. You'll have more problems later. You can also write a string parser. But expect the code to be lengthy.

Comment: @Fawaz This would be trivial using a regular expression ...until it isn't. If you could guarantee that the input has regular grammar, the problem could be solved by a regular expression. In all other cases, you need to actually parse the string to extract the tag you want.

Comment: @deceze: Okay, if I specify to extract the only one tag: `<img>`. Then ??

Comment: @Fawaz Take for example `<img src="foo.jpg" alt="<Awesome!>">`. The nested `<>` would trip up regular expressions. You can't tell whether the `>` is closing the tag or is part of an attribute until you parse the text, something that's not possible with regular expressions or any naïve text manipulation method. That's why: If you could guarantee that the input is regular enough to be handled by regular expressions, you won't need a parser. I doubt you can guarantee that though.

Answer (score 1):

delete HTML Tags Without `<img>` and `<a>` and `<br/>` and `<hr/>` and ...

```
$img = "
        <img src='/img/fawaz.jpg' alt= '' />
        <br /><br/>
        <hr/>
        <p> This is a detailed paragraph about Fawaz and his mates.</p>
        <a href='cft'>123</a>
        ";
$img = strip_tags($img , "<img>|<a>|<br>|<hr>");
echo $img;
```